# VBA convert column of sentences to column of single words

Tags: excel, vba

I have run into a small problem, as probably you can see I am not a master of VBA. 
My set input like this (all in one column, much longer):

1. Nice to meet you.
2. Nice to meet you too.
3. What is your name?
4. My name is Jack.
   .....

As a result I am looking for:

1. Nice
2. to
3. meet
4. you.
5. Nice
6. to
7. meet
8. you
9. too.
10. What
11. is
12. your
13. name?
14. My
    ...

Perfect reslut would be every sentence separated into unique words without punctuation marks in the list.

The code I have so far is:

```
Sub splitAddress()
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strAddressParts() As String
    Dim numParts As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rwIndex As Integer
    Dim colIndex As Integer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For rwIndex = 2 To lastRow
        strAddress = Range("C" & rwIndex).Value

        strAddressParts = Split(strAddress, " ")
        numParts = UBound(strAddressParts) + 1

        Range("I2").Resize(numParts).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strAddressParts)
    Next
End Sub
```

It seems to be working, but it overwrites the cells. Can you please help me?

Comment: You were really close! See my answer for what you were missing. :) Also, by "unique", do you mean that "Nice", for example, should appear only once in the new list?

Comment: By unique I mean exactly what what you said, how can I achieve it?

Comment: On mobile now so pardon typos. You have two options here: emulating the Remove Duplicates action and applying it on Column I, or you can use a scripting dictionary. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (very rudimentary modification of your code) and see my screenshot after:

```
Sub splitAddress()
    Dim strAddress As String
    Dim strAddressParts() As String, rStr As String
    Dim numParts As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowTwo, nextEmptyRow
    Dim rwIndex As Integer
    Dim colIndex As Integer
    Dim Cell As Range

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    For rwIndex = 2 To lastRow
        strAddress = Range("C" & rwIndex).Value

        strAddressParts = Split(strAddress, " ")
        numParts = UBound(strAddressParts) + 1

        lastRowTwo = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
        nextEmptyRow = lastRowTwo + 1
        Range("I" & nextEmptyRow).Resize(numParts).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strAddressParts)
    Next

    lastRowTwo = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each Cell In Range("I2:I" & lastRowTwo)
        rStr = Strip(Cell.Value)
        Cell.Value = rStr
    Next Cell

End Sub

Function Strip(WeeWoo As String) As String
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        Strip = .Replace(WeeWoo, "")
    End With
End Function
```

First off, you should be targeting the next empty row in column `I` for each iteration of the loop. You keep on target `I2`, which is why it's overwriting it. You were really close!

Now, I added a `RegEx` function that will check your newly created list and removes all non-letters and non-numbers. This basically strips the string of all punctuation marks and spaces. ;)

Hope this helps!

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I have missed the I2 cell :/

Comment: @brettdj: Thanks for that! I'm so brand new to `RegEx` myself that sometimes, the most obvious escapes me. Hopefully, checking against the above pattern is not much more expensive than checking versus your pattern. Otherwise, that's apersonal failure. :/ Lol.

Comment: @bk201 no more expensive code wise, just a few finger presses less :)